# Can't figure out why mocha test is passing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm learning to do testing in javascript and I have this mocha test that I'm running

```
describe("Fetches Coordinates", function() {
        it("searches the database for coordinates", function() {
            var boundary = routes.setBoundries(20, 80, 20, 80)
            routes.searchCoords(boundary, function(err,data) {
                expect(data.length).to.equal(100)
            });
        });
    });
```

And this is the method that it is using

```
exports.searchCoords = function searchCoords(boundary, callback){
     models.sequelize.query('SELECT "data".longitude, "data".latitude, "data".ipscount FROM ('
                + ' SELECT * FROM "DataPoints" as "data"'
                + ' WHERE "data".longitude BETWEEN '
                + boundary.xlowerbound + ' and ' + boundary.xupperbound + ') data'
                + ' WHERE "data".latitude BETWEEN '
                + boundary.ylowerbound + ' and '
                + boundary.yupperbound + ';', { type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                });                 
}
```

When I run the test it seems like Mocha just skips over the callback and passes. I can't seem to get this right. What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Testing asynchronous code with Mocha could not be simpler! Simply invoke the callback when your test is complete. By adding a callback (usually named done) to it() Mocha will know that it should wait for completion.

```
   it("searches the database for coordinates", function(done) {
        var boundary = routes.setBoundries(20, 80, 20, 80)
        routes.searchCoords(boundary, function(err,data) {
            expect(data.length).to.equal(100)
            done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Awesome! I saw that before but I guess I was putting it in the describe function rather than the it function. Thanks!